# Display Category item Count in Home controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm New To Rails :)

I have three models and two controllers in my app: Locations, Categories, and Pages

I want show items in a category with number (ex: testcategory (5)) in `pages#index`

Here is my code

```
<%= @categories.select{|category| category.name == "test"}.count %> but its return 1 but 3 item in the test category exist .
```

pages controller:

```
def index
  @locations = Location.all
  @categories = Category.all
end
```

category model:

```
has_many :locations
```

location model :

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :category
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the count of locations that belong to the "test" category.

```
<%= Category.find_by(name: 'test').locations.count %>
```

Comment: Hey Steve, I add this code in my view nothing happens, no error and no result. sorry for my english btw.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I did `<% ` but should've done `<%=`   Now fixed.  If you don't include the equal sign in the ERB file the Ruby code is executed but not displayed.

Comment: yay thanks, but can u help me how I can define a name for it ? now its just show 3. something like  nameOfCategory: (3) UPDATE : I got it my bad :) thanks again dude